# For loop through a string

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to print every character in the string `"Camus"`.

```
string_1 = "Camus"
x = 0

for string_1 in range(5):
    output_1 = (string_1[x])
    print(output_1)
    x =+ 1
```

But this throws an exception:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `string_1` is an integer from the `range()`. Did you mean to use `for x in ..` perhaps?

Comment: what would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Is `x =+ 1` a typo? That should be `x += 1`, right?

Comment: I'll try the 'for x in'

Comment: That works. Thank you so much @MartijnPieters

Comment: and yes it was a typo thank @MSeifert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print every character you don't need to index the string, just iterate over the string:

```
string_1 = "Camus"
for character in string_1:
    print(character)
```

You overwrite your `string_1` in each iteration so you'll get an integer as `string_1` which can't be subscripted. Therefore the exception.

If you want to index you need to use another iteration variable, like your `x`:

```
string_1 = "Camus"
for idx in range(5):
    print(string_1[idx])
```

If you wanted to do it with a custom index-variable you could also discard the iteration variable and do the increment with `+=`:

```
string_1 = "Camus"
idx = 0
for _ in range(5):
    print(string_1[idx])
    idx += 1
```

However, iterating over the string is probably the best way. :)